# T SQL insert statement results in object reference being inserted into empty data field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I've run into something very strange in SSMS that I can't seem to find researching it on the Internet. I have a package that runs nightly on a database inserting millions of records. It's a very straight forward script that simply imports data to a temp table and then inserts data from the temp table to another table. One of the fields in the import file has an ASCII blank space character for every single row, which normally just populates the temp table with a blank and nothing else.

Recently, some of the rows of the temp & final destination table are being populated with a string that looks like this:

```
label.ComponentCustomColumnRefValDesc.a41d368515c2198830d97c5528fc58c2
```

Does anyone have any idea where that could be coming from? Is it an object customization specification? If so, why would it be showing up as data in the table?

Comment: And the import file doesn't have this string, just an empty space still right?  (are you sure it's empty space and not an ASCII value that isn't space just not displayable?)

Comment: Also check the source file's columns that are *next to* your expected column.  If it's a delimited file and one of the previous columns' delimiter characters shows up an extra time or has stopped showing up, then you would be pulling in the wrong column data, unknowingly.